# Dimension mismatch with numpy broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am having trouble with numpy broadcasting. When I try to do a matrix-matrix multiplication, I get the following error:

"operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,6) (2,7)"

Here is the code that won't run:

```
import numpy as np

pointsX = np.array([0.5, 2, 3, 5.5, 8, 11])
pointsY = np.array([1, 2, -1.5, 0.5, 4, 5])
points = np.asarray([pointsX, pointsY])

linesX = np.array([0, 2, 4, 6, 10, 10, 0, 0])
linesY = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0])
lines = np.asarray([linesX, linesY])

x1 = linesX[0:-1]
y1 = linesY[0:-1]
L1 = np.asarray([x1, y1])

# calculate the relative length of the projection
# of each point onto each line
a = [np.diff(pointsX), np.diff(pointsY)]
b = points - L1
relativeProjectionLength = np.dot(a, b)/np.linalg.norm(b)
```

The problem occurs when I try to calculate **b**. I would expect it to be a [2x6x7] matrix. How do I perform this operation? I could try it with loops but the real data will be very big (~10000 points and ~10000 lines) and has to be high-performance.

I read about expanding the dimension of one of the operators (points or L1) but the following code does not solve the problem either:

```
b = points - L1[:,:,None]
b = points[:,:,None] - L1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend both to `3D`, keeping the first axis aligned and introducing new axes along the last one for `points` and second last one for `L1` and then subtract -

```
points[:,:,None] - L1[:,None,:] # or points[...,None] - L1[:,None]
```

Comment: That solved the problem. Now I even understand the examples of the official numpy broadcasting page better. Thank you!